# Inserting image to an editor

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using summer note editor and I want to upload an image to a folder when an user select an image file and at the same time I want to insert the image into the editor, How can achieve that, now I have the code that only upload the image to a folder but not into the editor...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote({
         height: 510,
          onImageUpload:function(files, editor, welEditable) {
              sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
          }

      });
      function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
          data = new FormData();
          data.append("file",file);
          $.ajax({
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              url: 'savetheuploadedfile.php',
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(url) {
                  editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
              }
          });
      } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, rather than using an editor object, replace the

```
editor.insertImage(welEditable,url);
```

with

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage',url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Summer note new version passes only one argument. So you can use this script

```
$('.summer').summernote({
    height: "200px",
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
        sendFile(files[0], $(this));
    }
});

function sendFile(file, editor) {
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);
$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'savetheuploadedfile.php',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(upload_file_url) {
        editor.summernote('insertImage', upload_file_url);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    }
});
```